Cómo hacer llamado de una función desde otro módulo a un Button
Estoy utilizando Python, Tkinter, MongoDB. Tengo tres módulos:

odonto.py: aquí realizo las ventanas tkinter
crearRegistro: aquí realizo la función crear un nueva persona
dataBase: la conexión de la base de datos.

Cuando junto todo en un sólo módulo todo funciona de maravilla, del mismo modo cuando separo el módulo de la base de datos con respecto al módulo de Tkinter(ventana) y la función crearRegistro.
Ahora bien, cuando separo por aparte el módulo Tkinter(ventanas) y la función crearRegistro, me crea problemas. Pues la función realizada lo llama un Button, pero sale un error al ser llamado.
No sé en que punto esta el error. Estoy aprendiendo, he leído y no logro identificar el problema.
Gracias
***dataBase.py***
from pymongo import MongoClient
try:
    client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
    baseDatos = client["odontoBd"]
    collection = baseDatos["paciente"]
    documents = collection.find()
    for documents in documents:
    print(documents)    
except Exception as ex:
    print("Error de conexión a la base de datos: {}".format(ex))
finally:
    client.close
    print("Conexión finalizada")


***crearRegistro.py***
import dataBase
from dataBase import collection
import odonto as o

nombrePaciente = o.nombrePaciente
edadPaciente = o.edadPaciente

def nuevoRegistro():    
    documents = {"nombrePac":nombrePaciente.get(),"edadPac":edadPaciente.get()}
   collection.insert_one(documents)

***odonto.py***
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from pymongo import MongoClient
import crearRegistro as cR

ventanaPrincipal = Tk()

Label(ventanaPrincipal,text="Nombre del paciente:").grid(row=3, column=0)
nombrePaciente = Entry(ventanaPrincipal)
nombrePaciente.grid(row=3, column=1)

Label(ventanaPrincipal,text="Edad del paciente:").grid(row=4, column=0)
edadPaciente = Entry(ventanaPrincipal)
edadPaciente.grid(row=4, column=1)

crear = Button(ventanaPrincipal,text="Crear Alumno", command = cR.nuevoRegistro, 
                                                           bg="green",fg="white")
crear.grid(row=5,columnspan=2)

ventanaPrincipal.mainloop()


Te estás metiendo en un berenjenal por culpa de intentar importar y usar variables globales en otros módulos... La causa última del error es que dado que odonto importa a dataBase y éste a su vez importa a odonto estás creando um import circular.
Si tu módulo odonto es tu módulo principal, no te compliques, dataBase no necesita conocer nada de la interfaz gráfica, pasa a a la función el nombre y la edad como argumentos y punto.
Además de esto, algunas observaciones:

Evita el uso de variables globales en lo posible y evita aún más importarlas y hacer uso de ellas en otros módulos. Hay mejores soluciones.

Intenta seguir las convenciones de estilo de PEP-8, son solo convenciones, pero ayudan a hacer tu código más legible.

Evita los imports "from módulo import *", se que en tkinter, por razones históricas que no termino de entender ni compartir, aparece por doquier, pero es una mala práctica en general.

En tu módulo dataBase vuelves a pecar de intentar importar variables globales. Ten en cuenta que collection puede que no llegue a existir nunca si se produce una excepción antes. Por otro lado, client.close no hace nada, no estás llamando al método (client.close()) y además, de nuevo, cliente puede que no llegue tampoco a existir siquiera si MongoClient("localhost", 27017) genera una excepción AttributeError.
Mete ese código en una función o clase. Además, posiblemente seria oportuno hacer uso del gestor de contexto para asegurarse de que la conexión se cierre adecuadamente.


En definitiva, podrías hacer algo como:
odonto.py
import tkinter as tk
import crear_registro as cr

ventana_principal = tk.Tk()

tk.Label(
    ventana_principal,
    text="Nombre del paciente:"
).grid(row=3, column=0)
nombre_paciente = tk.Entry(ventana_principal)
nombre_paciente.grid(row=3, column=1)

tk.Label(
    ventana_principal,
    text="Edad del paciente:"
).grid(row=4, column=0)
edad_paciente = tk.Entry(ventana_principal)
edad_paciente.grid(row=4, column=1)

crear = tk.Button(
    ventana_principal,
    text="Crear Alumno",
    command=lambda: cr.nuevo_registro(nombre_paciente.get(), edad_paciente.get()),
    bg="green", fg="white"
)
crear.grid(row=5, columnspan=2)

ventana_principal.mainloop()

crear_registro.py
from database import get_paciente_collection

def nuevo_registro(nombre_paciente, edad_paciente):
    documents = {
        "nombrePac": nombre_paciente,
        "edadPac": edad_paciente}
    with get_paciente_collection() as collection:
        collection.insert_one(documents)

database.py
from contextlib import contextmanager
from pymongo import MongoClient


@contextmanager
def get_paciente_collection():
    client = None
    try:
        client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
        base_datos = client["odontoBd"]
        collection = base_datos["paciente"]
        yield collection
    except Exception as ex:
        print(f"Error de conexión a la base de datos: {ex}")
    finally:
        if client is not None:
            client.close()


Buenas noches, gracias por el comentario. Lo colocó a prueba y  te informó.
Un abrazo

Buenas tardes. Todo funcionó a la perfección, gracias por su aporte y colaboración.
Bendiciones
